# breeze: creating inheritance in client-side model

Tags: breeze

I'm having a weird issue with the configureMetadataStore.

My model:

```
class SourceMaterial {
  List<Job> Jobs {get; set;}
}

class Job {
 public SourceMaterial SourceMaterial {get; set;}
}

class JobEditing : Job {}

class JobTranslation: Job {}
```

Module for configuring Job entities:

```
  angular.module('cdt.request.model').factory('jobModel', ['breeze', 'dataService', 'entityService', modelFunc]);

function modelFunc(breeze, dataService, entityService) {

    function Ctor() {
    }

    Ctor.extend = function (modelCtor) {
        modelCtor.prototype = new Ctor();
        modelCtor.prototype.constructor = modelCtor;
    };

    Ctor.prototype._configureMetadataStore = _configureMetadataStore;

    return Ctor;

    // constructor
    function jobCtor() {
        this.isScreenDeleted = null;
    }

    function _configureMetadataStore(entityName, metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(entityName, jobCtor, jobInitializer);
    }

    function jobInitializer(job) { /* do stuff here */ }
}
```

Module for configuring JobEditing entities:

```
angular.module('cdt.request.model').factory(jobEditingModel, ['jobModel', modelFunc]);

function modelFunc(jobModel) {

    function Ctor() {
        this.configureMetadataStore = configureMetadataStore;
    }

    jobModel.extend(Ctor);

    return Ctor;

    function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {
        return this._configureMetadataStore('JobEditing', metadataStore)     
    }
}
```

Module for configuring JobTranslation entities:

```
angular.module('cdt.request.model').factory(jobTranslationModel, ['jobModel', modelFunc]);

function modelFunc(jobModel) {

    function Ctor() {
        this.configureMetadataStore = configureMetadataStore;
    }

    jobModel.extend(Ctor);

    return Ctor;

    function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {
        return this._configureMetadataStore('JobTranslation', metadataStore)     
    }
}
```

Then Models are configured like this :

```
JobEditingModel.configureMetadataStore(dataService.manager.metadataStore);
JobTranslationModel.configureMetadataStore(dataService.manager.metadataStore);
```

Now when I call createEntity for a JobEditing, the instance is created and at some point, breeze calls `setNpValue` and adds the newly created Job to the np SourceMaterial.

That's all fine, except that it is added twice !

It happens when `rawAccessorFn(newValue);` is called. **In fact it is called twice**.

And if I add a new type of job (hence I register a new type with the metadataStore), then the new Job is added three times to the np.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help ?

**EDIT**

I've noticed that if I change:

```
   metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(entityName, jobCtor, jobInitializer);
```

to

```
   metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(entityName, null, jobInitializer);
```

Then everything works fine again ! So  the problem is registering the same jobCtor function. Should that not be possible ?

Answer (score 2):

## Our Bad

Let's start with a **Breeze bug**, recently discovered, in the Breeze "backingStore" model library adapter.

There's a part of that adapter which is responsible for rewriting data properties of the entity constructor so that they become observable and self-validating and it kicks in when register a type with `registerEntityTypeCtor`.

It tries to keep track of which properties it has rewritten. The bug is that it records the fact of rewrite on the EntityType rather than on the constructor function. Consequently, every time you registered a new type, it failed to realize that it had already rewritten the properties of the base `Job` type and re-wrapped the property.

This was happening to you. Every derived type that you registered re-wrapped/re-wrote the properties of the base type (and of its base type, etc).

In your example, a base class `Job` property would be re-written 3 times and its inner logic executed 3 times if you registered three of its sub-types. And the problem disappeared when you stopped registering constructors of sub-types.

We're working on a revised Breeze "backingStore" model library adapter that won't have this problem and, coincidentally, will behave better in test scenarios (that's how we found the bug in the first place).

## Your Bad?

Wow that's some hairy code you've got there. Why so complicated? In particular, why are you adding a one-time MetadataStore configuration to the prototypes of entity constructor functions?

I must be missing something. The code to register types is usually much smaller and simpler. I get that you want to put each type in its own file and have it self-register. The cost of that (as you've written it) is enormous bulk and complexity. Please reconsider your approach. Take a look at other Breeze samples, Zza-Node-Mongo for example.

Thanks for reporting the issue. Hang in there with us. A fix should be arriving soon ... I hope in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok, I'll wait for a bug fix then. Regarding your comment about my code, I don't see complexity in my code but I must be missing your point :) To me, it is natural to have a separation between model types (especially as the application grows). As far as I can see, the only difference between my code and the Zza-Node-Mongo sample, is that in the sample all models are in one big file, whereas I've separated my models in individual files.